# how to insert record to multiple tables with multiple file with linq2sql

Tags: linq-to-sql, asp.net-3.5

I have web application in asp.net 3.5. I just want to add record to 3 tables and one table contains multiple file details that I associated with table primary key value.

For more info I include this code:

```
protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsValid)
    {
        using (DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext())
        {
            int user_id = 0;
            var query = from u in db.Users
                        where u.Username == (String)Session["Username"]
                        select new
                        {
                            Id = u.Id
                        };
            foreach (var item in query)
            {
                if (item != null)
                {
                    user_id = int.Parse(item.Id.ToString());
                    break;
                }
            }
            Post myPost = new Post();
            myPost.Title = txt_ComName.Text.Trim();
            myPost.Category_id = int.Parse(DDL_Categorynames.SelectedItem
                                .Value.ToString());
            myPost.Description = txt_ComName1.Text.Trim();
            myPost.User_id = user_id;
            myPost.ToUser_id = user_id;
            if(file_upload.HasFile)
            {
                myPost.IsFileAttached = true;
            }
            else
            {
                myPost.IsFileAttached = false;
            }
            db.Posts.InsertOnSubmit(myPost);
            db.SubmitChanges();
            int newId = myPost.Id;
            Flag myFlag = new Flag();
            myFlag.IsRead = false;
            myFlag.IsImportant = false;
            myFlag.IsRemoved = false;
            myFlag.User_id = user_id;
            myFlag.Post_History_id = newId;
            db.Flags.InsertOnSubmit(myFlag);
            db.SubmitChanges();
            File myFile = new File();
            HttpFileCollection fileCollection = Request.Files;
            for (int i = 0; i < fileCollection.Count; i++)
            {
                HttpPostedFile uploadfile = fileCollection[i];
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(uploadfile.FileName);
                string fileType = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(fileName)
                                 .ToString().ToLower();
                myFile.Post_History_id = newId;
                myFile.File_name = fileName;
                myFile.File_ext = fileType;
                myFile.File_Size = uploadfile.ContentLength.ToString();
                if (uploadfile.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    uploadfile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/PostFiles/")
                                                           + fileName);
                    db.Files.InsertOnSubmit(myFile);
                    db.SubmitChanges();
                }
            }
            Panel_AddNew.Visible = false;
            Panel_ViewPostList.Visible = true;
            this.FillGrid();
        }
    }
}
```

However, with this scenario first file that was selected that was inserted and after that second file iterated then error occurred like:

> Cannot add an entity that already exists.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot add an entity that already exists.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 248:                    {
> Line 249:                        uploadfile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/PostFiles/") + FileName);
> Line 250:                        db.Files.InsertOnSubmit(myFile);
> Line 251:                        db.SubmitChanges();
> Line 252:                    }
>
> Source File: f:\EasyWeb\EndUser\Post_History.aspx.cs    Line: 250

please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new `File` in each iteration of the `foreach` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < fileCollection.Count; i++)
{
    File myFile = new File();
    HttpPostedFile uploadfile = fileCollection[i];
    ...
```